# Find the number of undefined properties in an object with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
let x =    {
      "name": undefined,
      "value": "tr",
      "prop1": undefined,
      "prop2": "test",
      "prop3": 123
    };
```

I need to find the number of properties that are undefined, so in this case 2.

Comment: Why do you want to use lodash? Vanilla JS is equally simple

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular JS:

Good comments pointed out that we can indeed immediately filter; more efficient:

```
Object.values(x).filter(v=> v === undefined).length
```

---

With Lodash

```
_.filter(x, (v, k) => v === undefined).length
```

Comment: You leave out the `.map()`. Using `Object.values(x).filter(v=>v===undefined).length` works just as well.

Comment: You don't need the entries, just the values, or the map. `Object.values(x).filter(v =>v===undefined).length;` Saves on space (array of values instead of 2d array) and avoids destructuring

Comment: Yep good suggestions. Indeed better. Will edit

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer it did! for the life of me i can not remember the lodash syntax! Need to practice more

Comment: Even if you keep the `entries` option, the `map` still looks very out of place. You can just do the filter directly off the `.entries` call: `Object.entries(x).filter(([_, v]) => v === undefined).length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.countBy()` to get an object (`counts`) that contains the number of time a  value appears in the the original object (`data`). You can then get the number of `undefined` values from the `counts` object:

```js
const data = { "name": undefined, "value": "tr", "prop1": undefined, "prop2": "test", "prop3": 123 };

const counts = _.countBy(data);

console.log(counts);

console.log(counts.undefined);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```